# SMS verification code not being sent

Tags: google-fabric

I'm using Twitter Digits to authenticate our users on both iOS and Android. For the last few days, I'm receiving various user reports saying that the verification SMS code never arrives... It's happening to me as well. The verification code is never sent but the "Call" option works fine.
I'm in Brazil right now but my phone has a US number and I receive/send other SMS just fine.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Probably best to email support(at)fabric(dot)io with this and the phone numbers and carriers having issues.

Comment: Will do. Thanks @MikeBonnell